# Cannot make <ActivityIndicatorIOS /> inside <Text />

Tags: ios, react-native

I am trying to put a loader inside `<Text></Text>` [react-native](/questions/tagged/react-native) element.

This loader is :

```
 <ActivityIndicatorIOS
               animating={this.state.isLoading}
               color="#fff"
               size="large"
              />
```

I got this error message in the emulator :

[image]

So , i try yo add `width` and `height` :

```
 <Text><ActivityIndicatorIOS
               animating={this.state.isLoading}
               color="#fff"
               size="large"
               width={20}
               height={20}
              />
 </Text>
```

Unfortunalty , it does not work too. the same error appears.

Comment: Maybe try `style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}` ?

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend putting anything besides text in the `<Text>` tags. 
What I would recommend is putting Text and ActivityIndicator in View tags:

```
<View>
     <Text>Your text</Text>
     <ActivityIndicator />
</View>
```

Also note that ActivityIndicatorIOS is deprecated and completely removed since react-native version 0.37-RC0 so use the cross platform ActivityIndicator for latest compatibility.